# Save function as alias

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, alias, functions

I am working on function that will resize and optimize all images in the directory with single command.

So far I created this function

```
function prepareimages() {

    # Resize Images
    for img in *.jpg; do
        convert -resize $1\! "$img" "$img"
    done

    # Optimize Images
    jpegoptim *.jpg
}
```

The idea is that I can use

```
prepareimages("400x300")
```

Then I tried to save the alias in .bashrc file, but dont know how to save it

I know you can save normal commands like

```
alias home="ssh root@123.11.11.11"
```

But is there way to save function as alias ?

```
alias prepareimages = prepareimages();
```

This doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work"? Also, function calls in the shell don't use parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an alias, you can save a function directly. Just save the definition into your `.bashrc` file.

To invoke it, use `prepareimages 400x300`, i.e. no parenhteses. You can use single or double quotes, but as there's no special character, they aren't needed.